# Clojure NullPointerException with sort-by

Tags: sorting, exception, clojure

Is this a bug or can I fix it somehow? (of course in my live code the similarity number is computed)

```clj
(sort-by :similarity > (for [ob [:a :b :c]] [:object ob :similarity 0.0]))
NullPointerException   clojure.lang.Numbers.ops (Numbers.java:961)
```

Using Clojure 1.6.0, Fedora 20x64, standard REPL.

**ADDED**
Why do I get that failure, but in (what I would expect to be analogous) this I'm okay:

```clj
user=> (sort-by :similarity > [{:shape "circle" :similarity 1.0}{:shape "square" :similarity 0.5}{:shape "triangle" :similarity 0.0}])
({:similarity 1.0, :shape "circle"} {:similarity 0.5, :shape "square"} {:similarity 0.0, :shape "triangle"})
```

Comment: One advantage of using a REPL is that when you run into problems like this, it's easy to evaluate sub-expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access vector elements by keyword, only by their index:

```clj
=> (get [:similarity 0.5] :similarity)
nil
=> (get [:similarity 0.5] 1)
0.5
```

So, you should use hashmap instead:

```
=> (get {:similarity 0.5} :similarity)
0.5
```

Here is how your code should look:

```
(sort-by :similarity > (for [ob [:a :b :c]] {:object ob :similarity 0.0}))
```

Comment: Pardon my being new to Clojure, but if I can't do vectors + keys, why does this work: (added to main question)

Comment: @WorldsEndless try running `(for [ob [:a :b :c]] [:object ob :similarity 0.0])` in REPL and you'll see that it's different.

Comment: Then compare it with my version `(for [ob [:a :b :c]] {:object ob :similarity 0.0})`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
=> (map :similarity (for [ob [:a :b :c]] [:object ob :similarity 0.0]))
(nil nil nil)
=> (for [ob [:a :b :c]] [:object ob :similarity 0.0])
([:object :a :similarity 0.0] [:object :b :similarity 0.0] [:object :c :similarity 0.0])
```